# How to remove focus from a single control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my C# WinForms program, I have a form that has only a single Button control on it.
By default, that Button control receives the focus on the form. But I don't want the Button to ever get focus.

Is there a solution, even one that would require a call to an unmanaged API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your form `Load` event you can set the focus on some other control.

If you do not want the control to ever get focus via keyboard, you can also set its `TabStop` property to false.

If you want that the button should not have focus when you open the form, then you need to correct the `TabIndex` property. The `TabIndex` property has an integer as value which specifies the order in which the controls get focus when `tab` key is pressed. If the control has `TabIndex` set to 0 then change it to some other value.

Check the documentation for [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx) and [TabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop.aspx) properties on MSDN.

Comment: as u noticed, i set the TabStop property of the button to false at form's Load event. it worked. but when the user clicks on the button, it holds the focus on itself. how to lose it again? i have only this button (and some Lables) on my form. Thanks.

Comment: @user434186, when the user clicks the button you probably have some code that handles this, just add a line to focus one of the labels, like: label.Focus(), it should work.

Comment: Ah! it works. when the user clicks the button i set on of the lables's focus. i didn't know Label can get focus too! thanks Adrian!

Answer (score 4):

Use `TabStop` property of button

```
button1.TabStop = false;
```

Comment: does not work with object sender `private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { (sender as button).TabStop = false; }`